# For loop advancing too quickly without generating random strings properly

Tags: c#, for-loop, random

So I coded a quick program to test how much difference it would make (in terms of processing speed) to check a boolean inside a foreach statement compared to checking it in a conditional statement outside of the loop. To test this I made a function generate random strings and add them to a list, but the for loop that generates the strings seems to advance too quickly without generating different strings in ever repetition. To fix this I added a `Thread.Sleep(15)` (15 milliseconds seems to be the minimum required to generate a different string in every repetition).

My question is this: is it possible to fix this issue without a `Thread.Sleep(15)`? Waiting 15 milliseconds between every repetition makes it so that the program takes a way bigger amount of time to run, which makes it highly unpractical for it's purpose (if I want to get statistically relevant data I'd have to run it around 10 thousand times for each option (the "good" and the "bad" way)). Here's the for loop in question:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

                var stringChars = new char[8];
                var random = new Random();

                for (int n = 0; n < stringChars.Length; n++)
                {
                    stringChars[n] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
                }

                var finalString = new String(stringChars);
                data.Add(finalString);
                Thread.Sleep(15);
        }
```

Comment: You should create the `Random()` outside of your `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. Will accept the answer as soon as it allows me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are getting is that you are recreating the `Random` class each time you iterate the loop.

The reason this is a problem is because the default seed for the `Random` class is the current system timestamp, which on repeated iterations could well be the same value.

Creating the `Random` outside of the `for` loop will ensure that a pseduo-random sequence is generated as you would expect.

Try this:

```
var random = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    var stringChars = new char[8];

    for (int n = 0; n < stringChars.Length; n++)
    {
        stringChars[n] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
    }

    var finalString = new String(stringChars);
    data.Add(finalString);
}
```